# How to convert ng-repeat to ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am not getting how the ng-model are connected to the ng-repeat options. How can the code below be converted to an ng-repeat? I can get the ng-repeat work but

> ng-selected="{{alternative.code == question.answer}}"

is what I don't understand how to do with the ng-options.

```
<select ng-model="question.answer">
   <option ng-selected="{{alternative.code == question.answer}}"
            ng-repeat="alternative in question.alternatives"
            value="{{alternative.code}}">{{alternative.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You do not have to use double brackets in your ng-selected attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<select ng-model="question.answer"
        ng-options="alternative.code as alternative.label for alternative in question.alternatives">
</select>
```

if `question.alternatives` is an array and the following:

```
<select ng-model="question.answer"
        ng-options="alternative.code as alternative.label for (key, alternative) in question.alternatives">
</select>
```

if it is an object. Both expressions start with the syntax `value as label`, which tells the `<select>` what to consider a value (to be bound to model) and what to use as a label (visible for users). The whole business with "this option has that value and is selected when model has it too" is then done automatically. [See documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="question.answer" ng-options="alt.code for alt in question.alternatives"></select>
```

*modelValue as optionLabelValue for item in array* if '*modelValue as*' is ommited modelValue is considered as item object